# how to save image after customization

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

some of the script like t-shirt design script,mug designer available for customization. For an example. we add text, rotate text, change color of text add/upload image re-size image etc after customization they give image as we customize. 
how to save this all customization as image ? 
any this type of script in php available ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you want is to take modifications made by JavaScript to an image in a browser and "save them" to a new image using PHP?

I am not sure how you'd go about doing that without regenerating the whole thing in PHP.

If I *had* to do it, I'd save all the modifications in an array in Javascript and using jQuery/AJAX send a request to the PHP file along with those modifications and have the PHP script re-do the things, for example write text on the source image, re-size it, add shapes and what-not.

However, this *might* end up being quite a time consuming task.